# Unable to removeapp by using appium - getting an exception

Tags: appium, java-client

I've tried

```
driver.removeApp("com.my.app");
```

but getting an exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: undefined status object (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

and the appium log :

```
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/71a4c5ca-92b5-4e94-99f5-f8a795671d82/appium/device/remove_app {"bundleId":"com.my.app"}

info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":1,"value":{"message":"undefined status object"},"sessionId":"71a4c5ca-92b5-4e94-99f5-f8a795671d82"}

info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/71a4c5ca-92b5-4e94-99f5-f8a795671d82/appium/device/remove_app 500 1.802 ms - 109
```

any idea why it doesn't work ?

thanks

Comment: This is working fine for me. Can you please share entire code where you are using this!

Comment: @Gaurav which client do you use ? I'm using java_client 3.1 , appium ver 1.4.1 IOS 8.4 iphone 5s simulator - not a real device